# Could a planet have oceans of heavy water?

Tags: chemistry, water

Heavy water, or deuterium oxide, is a form of water where the hydrogen atoms contain a proton and a neutron, rather than just a proton as in “normal water”. It is toxic to earth life but luckily, on earth at least, it occurs extremely rarely, at a frequency of 1 molecule in every 3,200 normal water molecules.

I would like, in my science fiction universe, to have an alien planet whose hydrosphere is made up of heavy water instead of normal water. What are the physical processes required for a planet like this to occur?

Comment: Why do you want heavy water?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How concerned are you with scientific plausibility?

Practically all the [deuterium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium) in the universe was created in the Big Bang; nuclear fusion processes in stars consume it, rather than producing a surplus. Comets and Earth's oceans are significantly enriched in deuterium (about 156 atoms of deuterium per million of ordinary hydrogen) compared to the proportion formed in the Big Bang (about 26 atoms per million), and the reasons for this are the subject of research.

I could believe in natural processes enriching the comets that provided the water for your hydrosphere up to, say, 1% deuterium in hydrogen, but a hydrosphere with nearly pure deuterium just isn't plausible as something that happened naturally.

Will your story work if the planet was terraformed by beings who either

- Wanted to do experiments in a heavy water-based biosphere, or
- Were whimsical enough to create one for the fun of it?

Doing the job would require processing a significant fraction of a star system's Oort cloud to extract the necessary deuterium. They'd also have to remove the old hydrosphere to avoid it contaminating the new one. Occasional comets would hit your planet over geological time and dilute it anyway.